# Digit sum of natural numbers in interval

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

can you help me with this problem ?

How many natural numbers $n$, $1 ≤ n ≤ 10^4$, with digit sum $= 7$, can you find ?

Comment: Which programming contest?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  This is a classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) question.  The digit sum of $7$ are the stars, increased to $10$ (why not $11$?) to account for zeros.  The bars are dividers that separate the digits.

Comment: So the solution is C(10,3) ?